# Initializing static member variable in a function

Tags: python

Is it possible to have static variables within class functions(as in C++).
The following does not give me what is desired.
The motivation is to initialize(very expensive process) a lookup list inside a function - but only if and when it is called.
Subsequent invocations of the same function should not need the variable to be initialized again.
Is there an idiom to achieve this?
Its fine if the function is aligned to the class;so that the value of rules is then available to all instances of 'A'

```
>>> class A:
...     def func(self):
...         if not hasattr(self.func,"rules"):
...             print 'initialize'
...             rules=[8,7,6]
...         rules.append(4)
...         return rules
...         
>>> a=A()
>>> for x in range(5):
...     print a.func()
...     

initialize
[8, 7, 6, 4]
initialize
[8, 7, 6, 4]
initialize
[8, 7, 6, 4]
initialize
[8, 7, 6, 4]
initialize
[8, 7, 6, 4]
```

Comment: Do you want that variable "rules" to be associated with the class or with the instance?

Comment: with the class  - I have edited the question to reflect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A(object): # subclass object for newstyle class
    def func(self, rules=[]):
        if not rules:
            rules[:] = [8, 7, 6]        
        rules.append(4)
        return rules
```

---

```
>>> a = A()
>>> for x in range(5):
        print a.func()


[8, 7, 6, 4]
[8, 7, 6, 4, 4]
[8, 7, 6, 4, 4, 4]
[8, 7, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[8, 7, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: but that would calculate rules on parsing `A`, not on first use.

Comment: @ThomasFenzl sorry missed that part

Comment: @ThomasFenzl I've fixed that now

Comment: This is perfect - but please explain the principle behind this.What makes this behave differently from hasattr?

Comment: @IUnknown `rules` is a member of the function itself. It begins empty, on the first run of `func()` it gets filled with `[8, 7, 6]`

Comment: @IUnknown: `hasattr` works fine.  The problem is that in your version you are not setting any attributes.  You're just creating a local variable `rules` that does not persist beyond a single function invocation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the variable to be associated with the class, store it on the class:

```
class A(object):
    def func(self):
        if not hasattr(A,"rules"):
            print 'initialize'
            A.rules=[8,7,6]
        A.rules.append(4)
        return rules
```